# Biblatex (footcite) and microtype

Tags: biblatex, biber, small-caps, microtype

Biblatex is configured so that all author names are written in small caps and microtype is set to to adjust the spacing between the small cap letters a la

```
\SetTracking{ encoding = *, shape = sc }{ 45 }
```

and this working pretty well for the document as well as the bibliography, alas it doesn't work for footcites. Is there a way to apply this spacing also for footcites?

What I tried, is

```
\SetTracking[ context = footcite]{ encoding = *, shape = sc }{ 45 }
\SetTracking[ context = footnote]{ encoding = *, shape = sc }{ 45 }
```

but it had no effect.

Comment: Please post a Minimal Working Example i.e. a complete, small document demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: harryhallerBiblatexLetterspacingFootcites]

```
% arara: pdflatex 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=authoryear
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{blindtext}   
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\SetTracking{ encoding = *, font = sc }{ 400 } 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{wurscht,
      author    =   {Wurschtel, Willi},
      title     =   {Wiener Würstchen und Bockwurst},
      journal   =   {Brühwurst und andere Leckereien},
      year      =   2015,
      pages     =   {32--39},
      number    =   4}
\end{filecontents}
\setlength{\textheight}{5cm}
\begin{document}
Die letzten Worte von \citeauthor{wurscht}: \enquote{Wer will warme
    \textsc{Wiener Würstchen}?}\footcite[S.~23]{wurscht}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```